# Ubuntu Videos: "Could not initialise OpenGL support" - Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: 22.10, video-player, mp4

I'm having a problem playing a .mp4 (don't know the codec used) video using Ubuntu Videos (the stock player) on RPi 4. I'm using Ubuntu 22.10 (upgraded from 22.04). I get the above error "Could not initialise OpenGL support" (with a spelling mistake :) ).

I tried running "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall", but all the drivers have already been installed. My OS is also fully updated.

What can I do to fix this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: OK. It turns out that VLC plays the video fine... But I still want to fix the Ubuntu player.

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/install-media-codecs-ubuntu/

Comment: @24601 didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and couldn't find a solution yet.